# Laurent uniform convergence on boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Fix an annulus $D=\{a<|z|<b\}$ and let $f(z)$ be a continuous function on its boundary $\partial D$.

Show that $f(z)$ can be approximated uniformly on $\partial D$ by polynomials in $z$ and $\frac{1}{z}$, if and only if,

$f$ has continuous extension to the closed annulus $D \cup \partial D$ that is analytic on $D$.

I have tried to show "only if" part, first. I have proved Laurent series exist on $\partial D$, pointwisely.

However, I have trouble to show uniform convergence on $\partial D$.

Comment: Immediate if you know [Runge's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_theorem).

Comment: In general it is not true that the Laurent series converges on $\partial D$ when assuming only that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean uniform convergence as functions to the Riemann sphere? (try with $f(z)=1/z,a=0,b=1$). Or maybe you meant $0<a<b<\infty$, this what I'll assume.

- One direction is easy: the uniform convergence to $f$ of a sequence of Laurent polynomials implies that $f$ is continuous.
- For the other direction, assuming $f$ is analytic on the annulus and extends continuously to the boundary:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n z^n +\sum_{n< 0} c_n z^n=g(z)+h(z)$$ where both $g,h$ extend continuously to the boundary.

Whence, as $\epsilon\to 0^+$,
$h(\frac{z}{1-\epsilon})\to h(z)$ and $g((1-\epsilon)z)\to g(z)$ uniformly.

Let $$t_\epsilon= \sup_{a\le |z|\le b} |f(z)-h(\frac{z}{1-\epsilon})-g((1-\epsilon)z)|$$

There is $M_\epsilon$ such that $\sum_{|n|>M_\epsilon} |c_n| (1-\epsilon)^{|n|} |z|^n <t_\epsilon$ on $a\le |z|\le b$ so that $$f_\epsilon(z)=\sum_{|n|\le M_\epsilon} c_n (1-\epsilon)^{|n|} z^n$$ is your sequence of Laurent polynomials approximations to $f$.